# distributing data from one table to multiple tables in sql server

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 3 tables:

Item_Detail  -----------------ID, Name

ItemPurchased_Detail ---QtyPurchased , RateOfPurchase  , DiscountReceived

ItemSold_Detail -----------QtySold , RateofSale , DiscountGiven

Also, i have a MAIN TABLE, ITEM_FULL_DETAIL, which contains all the columns from above 3 tables.

i have a winform application, with a single form which contains all the textboxes to insert data in the ITEM_FULL_DETAIL table. the user would input all the data, and click the SUBMIT button

i want to insert data first in the MAIN TABLE, and then it should distribute data individually to all the 3 tables. for this what shall i use? like triggers, porcedures, or views or joins?

Also, am using the ITEM_FULL_DETAIL table, because i want to protect my actual tables from any loss of data such as in case of power outage.

Shall I use a temporary table in place of ITEM_FULL_DETAIL table or is it fine using the current one only?

Is there any other way also?

Answer (score 1):

You can use database triggers or insert all records on the application level.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably re-think your design: duplicating the same data in different tables is usually a bad idea. In this case, you could replace ITEM_FULL_DETAIL with a view, then maintain the data in the underlying tables. That way you only have one copy of the data, so you don't need to worry about inconsistencies between tables.

If you did that then you could either insert new data into the 3 underlying tables in the correct order (probably the best idea) or use an INSTEAD OF trigger on the ITEM_FULL_DETAIL view (more complicated). The INSERTs can be done using an ORM, ADO.NET, a stored procedure or whatever suits your application design best.

If you do have a good reason for duplicating your data, then it would be helpful if you could share it, because someone may have a better suggestion for that scenario.

Comment: sir, if i use a view, then it can't update 3 tables simultaneously ? so please help, how do i use view in this situation

Comment: @sqlchild: the advantage of the view is that it avoids duplicating data. To update 3 tables you will always need 3 UPDATE statements, the only question is where to put them: in a trigger, in a procedure or in your application. The answer depends on your application design, e.g. are you using an ORM or not? Are you avoiding putting code in the database or not? Etc. Finally, as Josh pointed out, whatever solution you choose you should consider using transactions for related updates that must complete or fail together.

Comment: i am not familiar with ORM, i can only tell that am using insert query of t-sql

Answer (score 1):

> Also, am using the ITEM_FULL_DETAIL table, because i want to protect my actual tables from any loss of data such as in case of power outage.

..What? How do you suppose you are protecting your tables? What are you trying to prevent? There is absolutely no need to have the `ITEM_FULL_DETAIL` table if what you are worried about is data integrity. You're probably creating a situation in which data integrity can be compromised by using this intermediate table.

Are you aware of transactions? Use them. If two out of three tables are written to, then the power on the client goes off and can't complete the 3rd write, the transaction will fail and the partial data will be rolled back.

Unless I'm totally missing the point here..